# Hive alter statement on a partitioned table

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have a empty partitioned table in Hive and i am trying to name of a column along with the order of columns in the table :

```
    > describe formatted test_hive;
```

## col_name              data_type               comment

col1                 date
col2                 string
col3                 string
abc                     decimal(11,2)

## Partition Information

## col_name              data_type               comment

mth_year           string

Trying to rename abc to xyz and moving it after col1 , but when i run

```
alter table test_hive partition(mth_year)  CHANGE abc  xyz DECIMAL(11,2) AFTER col1;
```

but getting error :

```
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10006]: Partition not found {proc_mth_year=null}
```

Can we do alter on empty partition table ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to note the specific partition, e.g. -

```
alter table test_hive partition (mth_year='03_2017') 
change abc xyz decimal(11,2) after col1
;
```

or doing it in the table level -

```
alter table test_hive
change abc xyz decimal(11,2) after col1
cascade
;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer , it worked. Will it be wiser to add CASCADE as well since we are altering at the table level ?

Comment: If it for the whole table and not just new partitions, so 'Yes'